# whereas when I use single value it throws an error. Uncaught TypeError: health.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

- i am new to js.
- when I use array for health map method works fine
- whereas when I use single value it throws an error. Uncaught TypeError: health.map is not a function
- can you tell me how to fix it..
- providing my code below.

working input

```or-tag-here
let health =[{ "addedByName":"player", "mobileVersion":"sa,ple.txt" },
         { "addedByName":"player", "mobileVersion":"sa,ple.pdf" }
        ];
```

not working input

```or-tag-here
let health ={ "addedByName":"player", "mobileVersion":"sa,ple.txt" };
```

breaking fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fq9ucpcb/

```or-tag-here
let health ={ "addedByName":"player", "mobileVersion":"sa,ple.txt" };

let types = ["text/plain", "application/pdf"];

let downloads = health.map(function(version) {
                  let ext = version.mobileVersion.replace(/.*(?=\.\w+)/, "");
```

Comment: You can't map an object. What did you want it to do? Mapping only makes senses for sequential containers, which plain objects aren't.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is only available for Arrays, which is why you're getting the error when you try to use it on an Object.

If you want to loop through the properties of an Object, you can use a method like [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

map is prototype method for Array Class. map method works on each element in an Array.

---

let health ={ "addedByName":"player", "mobileVersion":"sample.txt" };

---

'health' is an object and you are trying to call map() method on this health Object.So here you are getting  Error 'Uncaught TypeError: health.map is not a function' means this map() is not function for Object(health).

Answer (score 1):

"health" is not an Array. The "map" method can only be used on arrays. Health is an object with properties, and those properties need to be unique. You can modify a property using property accessors like "." (dot notation) or property[property name'] (bracket notation). If you have an object with similar properties, you can use a "for in" loop and a regular expression, or other string matching methods to modify those property values.

```js
let health = {
  "addedByName": "player",
  "mobileVersion": "sa,ple.txt"
};

let types = ["text/plain", "application/pdf"];

let downloads = health.mobileVersion.replace(/.*(?=\.\w+)/, "")

console.log(downloads);
```

Comment: @texirv your "map function" encompasses a range of functionality. Outside the scope of this question. I can't decouple your code. Maybe you can narrow down the problem and ask another question :)